# How can I find out about the Oklahoma Children’s Home (Finding) Society

Tags: records, adoption, locating-records, oklahoma

Searching for records/lists/info from this organization after it moved from Guthrie Oklahoma to Oklahoma City. Anyone know if there is a book or anything about the history of this particular branch of the Children’s Home Society?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the OrphanFinder.com/Oklahoma page for information about many orphanages and records in Oklahoma.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the page, and a brief description of what sort of information they have -- that will make this answer much more useful. Thanks.